# Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 with USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mac, macosx

**controller found and freeze**

I am trying to install ubuntu to my old mac. I have portioned the Memory and added the ubuntu.dmg to the USB Drive. I have tried both Ubuntu 64 and 32 bit, and so far both bring me to this image below. I have looked all over the forums and webs to try and solve this problem and have found nothing. I was following [this tutorial](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/11/ubuntu-on-a-macbookpro-82-running-yosemite/) and I edited the main config for refind, but when I ran `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/Disk0s1 /Volumes/esp` in a terminal the output was

```
Resource Busy
```

[Picture of the screen after booting the USB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90qss.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add further detail. For instance you could expand on exactly what "configs" you edited, expand on what you tried and what happened. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Theres not really much detail to tell. I did what most tutorials for this tell you. I had only one problem and it was when I edited the main config for refine, I was after supposed to run `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/Disk0s1 /Volumes/esp` in a terminal and the output was "Resource Busy".


[Tutorial I Used](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/11/ubuntu-on-a-macbookpro-82-running-yosemite/)

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing you should [edit] into your post. I did it for you this time.

Comment: What is the model of your Mac?. I just installed Ubuntu 64 bit to an external drive using my iMac 20 inch Mid 2007. If you want I can supply the procedure I used.

Comment: The mac is a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009). I wonder how different you the procedure you took was, to the one I took. At this point I'm willing to try any suggestions.

Comment: Do you what it install using a DVD or a USB flash drive? Using a DVD is the recommended method. This install will be 64 bit and be EFI/GPT based. I assume you have OS X installed on this Mac? If so, which version? How much space were you going to allow for Ubuntu? You will need to download a free copy of `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` from this site [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the Ubuntu bootable usb choice on your mac? If not, the bootable usb is not created properly. You can check this [link](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-mac-in-os-x--cms-21253) to verify you have done it correctly.

Comment: I tried what you said and it changed what it says depending on how I try to boot it. I get `i8042: No Controller Found` if I try to boot `EFI\boot\grubx64.efi`or the penguin on the boot option.(I get the same thing if I try the Fallback option) and when I try to Boot Legacy OS from whole disk volume. I get a the original problem with an occasional usb error.(will post picture in main post.)

Comment: [Picture of Occasional Output](http://imgur.com/jxw39Bk)

Comment: Does it matter that a USB flash drive, created using the method at your link, does not verify?